# I'm trying to check a sentence for digits. The code seems to stop running after the first word of the sentence

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class DigitSumming {

    public static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println ("Please enter a sentence: ");
        String userSentence = in.next();

        //writing for loop to check each character
        int sum = 0;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < userSentence.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isDigit(userSentence.charAt(i))){
                System.out.println("number: "+ userSentence.charAt(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what i get when i run the program:

```
Please enter a sentence: 

7 ate 9
```

Output:

```
number: 7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `nextLine()` instead of just `next()`.

Corrected code snippet:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class DigitSumming {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println ("Please enter a sentence: ");
        /* Corrected Here */
        String userSentence = in.nextLine();

        //writing for loop to check each character
        int sum = 0, i;
        for (i = 0; i < userSentence.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isDigit(userSentence.charAt(i))){
                System.out.println("number: "+ userSentence.charAt(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Input:

```
7 ate 9
```

Output:

```
number: 7
number: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

You should invoke `nextLine` on your `Scanner`.

Otherwise, the default delimiter will be used (white space), so `userSentence` is only `"7"`.

From the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29):

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern.

... and also:

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace.